# How Do i handle both the checked and clicked events in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

Say I have a form  and onload of that form I have  2 radio buttons say "yes" or "no "
I have set of action to perform  when we select either one radio button .Say if we select "yes "

```
//Onload of Form 
if(("#yes:checked")){
$("#table").show();
$("#div1").show();
$("#div2").show();
alert("Checkedd on Load");
}
```

//for click

```
$("#yes").bind('click',function(){ 
    $("#table").show(); 
    $("#div1").show(); 
    $("#div2").show(); 
    alert("Checked by  Click"); }); 
    });
```

Iam Writing the same repeated lines of code for two similar set of events .Is There anyway to combine the "Checked" and "Clicked" events 
Say if i do inthis way than  "Checked" doesnot get called untill "Clicked"?Is there any other way to do it.

```
$("#yes").bind('click',function(){
if(("#yes:checked")){
$("#table").show();
$("#div1").show();
$("#div2").show();
alert("Checked by  Click");
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine multiple events with `.bind()` like

```
$('#yes').bind('click change', function(e) {
});
```

You can lookup the `event object` to determine which event actually was triggered

```
switch(e.type) {
   case 'click': {
       break;
   }
   case 'change': {
       break;
   }
}
```

If you want to execute the exact same code for those events, you can just skip the first `break` statement. Anyway, in your particular case I believe you only need the `change` event. In your event handler you just check if the element is currently checked or not:

```
if( this.checked ) {
}
else {
}
```

To execute the eventhandlers code when loading your site, you can `.trigger()` it like

```
$('#yes').bind('click change', function(e) {
}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: That is WAY more elegent that anything I could come up with. Awesome job jAndy! +1

Comment: Iam Not able get it working from what ever you have said above http://jsfiddle.net/XK6y7/

Comment: I second the comment. Very elegant. Didn't realize it could be done this way. jQuery continues to amaze me.

Comment: If i have two radio buttons Than it is always making the first radio button to select it as default. And it is resulting in 2 radio buttons Checked

Answer (score 0):

```
if(("#yes:checked")){
    processCheck();
    alert("Checked on Load");
}
$("#yes").bind('click',function(){ 
    processCheck()
    alert("Checked by  Click"); }); 
});

function processCheck() {
    $("#table").show();
    $("#div1").show();
    $("#div2").show();
}
```

That way you define the code once and call it multiple times :)

You could even write the alert into the function and give it the string desired:

```
function processCheck(msgStr) {
    $("#table").show();
    $("#div1").show();
    $("#div2").show();
    alert(msgStr);
}
```

And call something like `processCheck("Checked on Load");`

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to achieve it is to create a function which will do all the common operations, and then call this function when event occurs.

```
function show_stuff() {
  $("#table").show();
  $("#div1").show();
  $("#div2").show();
  alert("Checked by  Click");
}
```

and

```
 $("#yes").bind('click',function(){ 
     show_stuff(); 
  });
```